# Kubuntu Chromium not using the system icons

Tags: icons, kubuntu, chromium

I'm using Kubuntu 11.04 with Chromium 12.0.742.91 (87961) Ubuntu 11.04
My annoyance is that the menus and dialogues use a strange icons set which I presume to be a default Gnome one. How can I change this to something more similar to my KDE icon set?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to change the menu icons (perhaps by using an other chromium theme), but the icons (Back, Reload, etc) can be changed at *Preferences* -> *Personal Stuff*. (click on the wrench icon on the right to open the menu containing the *Preferenes* item)

At *Personal Stuff*, scroll down a bit till *Appearance*. Press the *Use GTK+ Theme* to get the icons used by the system (Dolphin, Firefox, etc).

[image: Chromium Preferences]

Comment: thanks for the answer but the menu icons and file dialogue are what i'm looking at changing

Answer (score 0):

The reason the file dialogue and certain other components do not look native, is that Chrome/ium is using GTK+ for desktop integration, and not Qt libraries. Since GTK+ is still missing some critical Qt integration features, you cannot get applications based on it to do everything you want.

Comment: thanks, i suspected something like this, but i'm also sure there's a way in KDE to change the default icons used by GTK+. any ideas?

Comment: @Dirk, while you might be able to change the icons, there is no guarantee that Chromium will pick up the changes. You could try restarting the application, but it might not take the changes.